# Excel: Deep reference possible? i.e. get base or origin cell from a cell that references it

Tags: excel

If I say that:

A4 = A3, A3 = A2, and A2=A1

All their values will be the same.  Great... however, what if I'm at A4 and want the cell that is one cell right of A1?  I can use OFFSET, normally, but in this case the offset would be relative to A3 and not A1.

Example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCtT4.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: There is no column to the left of A. Please re-phrase your question.

Comment: Excel does not allow you to track the references with formulas.  It is possible using `Trace Precedents` to walk the calculation tree of how things are related.  Unless this is idle curiosity, you may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I see what you're doing now.  The solution will depend largely on how your data is set up: how is a hammer related to wood and other items?  If you add a picture to your question and edit in a little info, it could be possible to put together a UDF (VBA function) that goes after this.  These sorts of recursive/hierarchical problems can be solved, but generally not with normal formulas.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  I am comfortable with coding but have never actually written scripts in excel.

Here is an example: http://i.imgur.com/uPIQPpj.png

The values with the relevant equations shown below.  Here I am calculating the 'tier' of the item which is one larger than the largest tier required to make the item.  It would be fantastic if I could automatically calculate the tier as I fill in the requirements as references.  Which would be trivial with a 'deep reference' in that MAX() equation.  I'm open to alternatives!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to do this.  One approach with your simple formulas though is to use `FORMULATEXT` `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET`.  If you know something about the formula, you can pull out the cell reference and use `INDIRECT` to make it a real reference.  From there, `OFFSET` will work as intended.

*I would not recommend actually using this technique for any serious purpose.  If you are doing this, you probably need to consider the design of the underlying spreadsheet.  Consider using a named ranged somewhere.*

**Formula** is in cell `E5` and is trying to pull a reference from the formula in cell `D4`.  `D4` is just looking at `C3`.  So ultimately, `OFFSET` will pull the value from `C4` since it is one row below `C3`.  I am using `RIGHT` to get the non-equal sign part of the formula; this is where knowledge of the formula is required.

```
E5=OFFSET(INDIRECT(RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(D4),2)), 1,0)
D4=C3
```

You could keep building these if you want to get your "deep reference" but it would require you to know how far to go.  It would also be a mess and use `INDIRECT` which is a volatile function.

**Picture of ranges and results**

[image: ranges and results]

Comment: Thanks for the well-written reply.

Use: to track the items and requirements in a crafting system for a game.  A hammer might require wood and steel.  However, many items will require wood.  So, when I have a row of information about the hammer such as its experience, requirement 1, requirement 2, and so forth I am referencing the cell that Wood is stored in so if we re-name wood it updates everywhere.

Now, in calculating the experience given for crafting a hammer I need properties of the requirements.  The relevant property of Wood is found 2 cells to the left of the cell with content "Wood"

Comment: I could simply reference that cell manually but there are hundreds of items and it would save me many hours if I could use the same form everywhere instead of manually finding those 3+ cell references for every item.